# Pagination issues with the grid component from Prestashop

Tags: pagination, datagrid, prestashop

Here is my issue, I'm currently developping a module for prestashop,
I am using two grid components to render grids for datas that
I inserted inside a table I created for my module .

I am using Prestashop 1.7.8.9 , and the default implementation provided by the documentation,
I created my own definitions,and query builders to use with the data factories and grid factories as told by the documentation.

The grid is displaying with no issues whatsoever , but when I use the pagination links it doesn't work.

When clicking on the links the offset value are accurate.
What could be the problem causing the issue ? Thank you .

I tried to have my pagination working, but it didn't .

here is my code :

```
<?php
namespace PrestaShop\Module\Stabs\Tables;
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Grid\Column\ColumnCollection;
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Grid\Column\Type\DataColumn;
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Grid\Definition\Factory\AbstractGridDefinitionFactory;













class GridCategoryExtrafields extends AbstractGridDefinitionFactory
{
    protected function getId()
    {
        return 'extrafields' ;
    }

    protected function getName()
    {
        return $this->trans('Category Features',[],'Admin.Advparameters.Feature') ;
    }

    protected function getColumns()
    {
        //id    id_category label_extrafield    is_excluded is_visible
        return(new ColumnCollection())
        ->add((new DataColumn('id'))
        ->setName($this->trans('ID',[],'Admin.Global'))
        ->setOptions([
            'field'=> 'id'
        ])
        )->add((new DataColumn('id_category'))
        ->setName($this->trans('ID catégorie',[],'Admin.Advparameters.Feature'))
        ->setOptions([
            'field' => 'id_category'
        ])
        )->add((new DataColumn('label_extrafield'))
        ->setName($this->trans('Label extrafield',[],'Admin.Advparameters.Feature'))
        ->setOptions([
            'field'=> 'label_extrafield'
        ])
        )->add((new DataColumn('is_excluded'))
        ->setName($this->trans('Exclu des imports',[],'Admin.Advparameters.Feature'))
        ->setOptions([
            'field'=> 'is_excluded'
        ])
        )->add((new DataColumn('is_visible'))
        ->setName($this->trans('Traité différement',[],'Admin.Advparameters.Feature'))
        ->setOptions([
            'field'=> 'is_visible'
        ]));
    }

    
}
```

```
<?php
namespace Prestashop\Module\Stabs\Tables;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Grid\Query\AbstractDoctrineQueryBuilder;






final class GridCategoryExtrafieldsQueryBuilder extends AbstractDoctrineQueryBuilder
{
    private $contextLangId;

    private $contextShopId;


   


    public function __construct(Connection $connection, $dbPrefix, $contextLangId, $contextShopId )
    {
        parent::__construct($connection, $dbPrefix);
        $this->contextLangId = $contextLangId;
        $this->contextShopId = $contextShopId;
    }

    public function getSearchQueryBuilder(\PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Grid\Search\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
    {
        $qb = $this->getBaseQuery();
        $qb->orderBy(
            $searchCriteria->getOrderBy(),
            $searchCriteria->getOrderWay()
        )
            ->setFirstResult($searchCriteria->getOffset())
            ->setMaxResults($searchCriteria->getLimit());
        
    

        foreach ($searchCriteria->getFilters() as $filtername => $filtervalue) {
            if ('id' == $filtername) {
                $qb->andWhere("id = :$filtername");
                $qb->setParameter($filtername, $filtervalue);
                continue;
            }
            $qb->andWhere("$filtername LIKE :$filtername");
            $qb->setParameter($filtername, '%' . $filtervalue . '%');
        }


        return $qb;
    }


    public function getCountQueryBuilder(\PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Grid\Search\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
    {
        $qb = $this->getBaseQuery();
        $qb->select('COUNT(id)');
        return $qb;
    }
    public function getBaseQuery()
    {
        return $this->connection
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from($this->dbPrefix . 'category_extrafield')
            ->select('id, id_category, label_extrafield, is_excluded, is_visible');
    }

}
```

```
 prestashop.module.stabs.tables.grid_visible_table:
    class: 'PrestaShop\Module\Stabs\Tables\GridVisibleTable'
    parent: 'prestashop.core.grid.definition.factory.abstract_grid_definition'
    public: true
  
  prestashop.module.stabs.tables.visible_query_builder:
    class: 'PrestaShop\Module\Stabs\Tables\VisibleQueryBuilder'
    parent: 'prestashop.core.grid.abstract_query_builder'
    arguments:
       - "@=service('prestashop.adapter.legacy.context').getContext().language.id"
       - "@=service('prestashop.adapter.legacy.context').getContext().shop.id"
    public: true 
  
  prestashop.module.stabs.visible_data_factory:
    class: 'PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Grid\Data\Factory\DoctrineGridDataFactory'
    arguments:
       - '@prestashop.module.stabs.tables.visible_query_builder'
       - '@prestashop.core.hook.dispatcher'
       - '@prestashop.core.grid.query.doctrine_query_parser'
       - 'visible'

  prestashop.core.grid.visible_grid_factory:
    class: 'PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Grid\GridFactory'
    arguments:
       - '@prestashop.module.stabs.tables.grid_visible_table'
       - '@prestashop.module.stabs.visible_data_factory'
       - '@prestashop.core.grid.filter.form_factory'
       - '@prestashop.core.hook.dispatcher'


  prestashop.module.stabs.tables.grid_category_extrafield_table:
    class: 'PrestaShop\Module\Stabs\Tables\GridCategoryExtrafields'
    parent: 'prestashop.core.grid.definition.factory.abstract_grid_definition'
    public: true
  
  prestashop.module.stabs.tables.grid_category_extrafield_query_builder:
    class: 'PrestaShop\Module\Stabs\Tables\GridCategoryExtrafieldsQueryBuilder'
    parent: 'prestashop.core.grid.abstract_query_builder'
    arguments:
       - "@=service('prestashop.adapter.legacy.context').getContext().language.id"
       - "@=service('prestashop.adapter.legacy.context').getContext().shop.id"
    public: true 
  
  prestashop.module.stabs.grid_category_extrafield_data_factory:
    class: 'PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Grid\Data\Factory\DoctrineGridDataFactory'
    arguments:
       - '@prestashop.module.stabs.tables.grid_category_extrafield_query_builder'
       - '@prestashop.core.hook.dispatcher'
       - '@prestashop.core.grid.query.doctrine_query_parser'
       - 'extrafields'

  prestashop.core.grid.grid_category_extrafield_factory:
    class: 'PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Grid\GridFactory'
    arguments:
       - '@prestashop.module.stabs.tables.grid_category_extrafield_table'
       - '@prestashop.module.stabs.grid_category_extrafield_data_factory'
       - '@prestashop.core.grid.filter.form_factory'
       - '@prestashop.core.hook.dispatcher'
```

```
            $SearchCriteria = new SearchCriteria([], 'id_product', 'DESC', 1, 10);
            $gridfactory = $this->get('prestashop.core.grid.visible_grid_factory');
            $visiblegrid = $gridfactory->getGrid($SearchCriteria);
    
            $SearchCriteriaExtrafields = new SearchCriteria([], 'id', 'ASC', null, 10);
            $gridextrafieldfactory = $this->get('prestashop.core.grid.grid_category_extrafield_factory');
            $extrafieldgrid = $gridextrafieldfactory->getGrid($SearchCriteriaExtrafields);

            return $this->render('@Modules/stabs/views/templates/admin/form.html.twig',[
                'formtitle' => $formname,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'extragrid' => $this->presentGrid($extrafieldgrid),  
                'grid' => $this->presentGrid($visiblegrid),
            ]);
```

the grids are both rendered at the same time with a form.
here is the documentation I used : https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/development/components/grid/

Comment: I added the javascript required for it to work it doesn't seems to do anything whatsoever